# Worklight: How to stop overscroll on Blackberry devices

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10

I am developing a hybrid application using IBM worklight, HTML5, css3, js and jquery mobile. I notice that the application has an overscroll effect or the bounce effect at both top and bottom of the page.

This happens only in BB9900, Z10 and Q10 devices.
The application works fine on Android and iPhone.

I tried the following:
Updated the config.xml file with following:

```
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

And:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverflowscroll" value="true" />
```

None of them works.
Is there a way out to remove the bounce effect on blackberry devices?

Comment: Did you find a way around the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that this can be achieved by using `data-bb-scroll-effect="off"`.

- See section "Screen Scrolling Effects: https://github.com/blackberry/bbUI.js/wiki/Screens
- And this BB dev forum topic: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Prevent-scrolling-on-BB10-Webworks-BBui-js/m-p/1911219#M29182

---

Some more things to try:

1. If you have the height set in the meta tag, it's best to leave that out.
2. It could be an issue with in CSS where there is height set to 100% and also using a 1px border, for example, which would cause it to overflow.

Note:
the preference in Cordova for config.xml is actually:

```
 <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
```

However, this is works in WebWorks 2.0 (solves it for the Z10/Q10).
Worklight does not officially support that version of WebWorks.

Comment: Thanks Idan for your reply. But, this solution does not work.

Comment: I suggest to also ask the question at BB's forums, as it pertains IMO more to BB than to Worklight.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set your viewport in the index.html to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

and your CSS body element to:

```
body {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;                /* prevent callout to copy image, etc when tap to hold */
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;             /* prevent webkit from resizing text to fit */
-webkit-user-select: none;                  /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
width: 100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

This snippet, along setting the height and width to the maximum size allowed, will ensure the experience is fit for mobile (no text selection, no tap to hold).